# validate google places autocomplete input in android

Tags: android, listview, autocomplete, google-places-api

How we can detect if user selected address from suggested List  and not accepting other entries like "kjkshkjjhd" in autocomplete text view with Google Places API?

```
AutoCompleteTextView places = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
    places.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line ));
    places.setOnItemClickListener(this);

 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```